# How to draw Tangent to any given curve using compass?

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives

I was curious if there was a way to construct tangent on a point on any given curve using basic geometry instruments. 
I tried looking on the Internet but there were articles which were circle specific only.

Comment: Depends on the curve. For conics, the answer is yes. For $y=\exp x$ the answer is also yes (if the axes are also given). You have to know some nice property of the curve that allows you to draw the tangent, as there is no "general" method.